# c# word wrap, how to limit new line creation based on different words in a string

Tags: c#, console-application, word-wrap

I've been looking into writing a word wrap console application in C#. I've found a lot of useful examples on here but I'm having issues with what I've currently got.

The code I've currently got will create a new line after every word that "overflows" the `columnLimit`. I want/need a way of adding a new line only if that word isn't the final one in the string and if possible to add a hyphen when the word *overflows* between two lines (so it will be a word splitter not a word wrapper).

I know it's probably a really simple solution but I'm new to C# and I'm really stuck on this problem. A coding solution so I can see where I've gone wrong would be ideal.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
public string formatText(string longSentence, int columnLimit)
{
    string[] words = longSentence.Split(' ');
    StringBuilder newLongSentence = new StringBuilder();
    string line = "";

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if ((line + word).Length > columnLimit)
        {
            newLongSentence.AppendLine(line);
            line = "";
        }

        line += string.Format("{0} ", word);
    }

    if (line.Length > 0) 
        newLongSentence.AppendLine(line);

    return newLongSentence.ToString();     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the length the the line goes over the limit to do a substring, making your `foreach` loop look more like this

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int extraLetters = columnLimit - (line + word).Length;
    if (extraLetters < 0 && extraLetters != word.Length)
    {

        newLongSentence.AppendLine(line + word.Substring(0, word.length + extraLetters));
        line = string.Format("{0} ", word.Substring(word.length + extraLetters + 1));

    }
    else if(extraLetters == word.Length)
    {
        newLongSentence.AppendLine(line);
        line = String.Format("{0} ", word);
    }
    else
    {
        line += string.Format("{0} ", word);
    }

}
```

If you wish to include a dash, take 1 away from the relevant substrings and add a dash like so

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    int extraLetters = columnLimit - (line + word).Length;
    if (extraLetters < 0 && extraLetters != word.Length && extraLetters != word.Length - 1)
    {

        newLongSentence.AppendLine(line + word.Substring(0, word.length + extraLetters - 1) + "-");
        line = string.Format("{0} ", word.Substring(word.length + extraLetters));

    }
    else if(extraLetters == word.Length || extraLetters == word.Length - 1)
    {
        newLongSentence.AppendLine(line);
        line = String.Format("{0} ", word);
    }
    else
    {
        line += string.Format("{0} ", word);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect - upon running the code however it still creates a new line even after the last word in the string.. any idea on how to fix that? (its the main issue that's causing my tests to fail)

Comment: When run it now causes a ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled on this line (newLongSentence.AppendLine(line + word.Substring(0, word.length + extraLetters - 1) + "-");                         the additional information says : Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: Alroght give me a few minutes to work this logic out, doing it without a compiler :/

Comment: Thank you :) (if its any help i'm using visual studio - it can be found for free on microsofts website )

Comment: Edited again, hopefully this works for you, I have visual studio but can't use it at this moment, that's all :)

Comment: With the bottom piece of code I still face this issue: arguementOutOfRangeException was unhandled : length cannot be less than zero... this is on the same line as previously - newLongSentence.AppendLine(line + word.Substring(0, word.Length + extraLetters - 1) + "-");

Comment: Supposedly the issue is being caused by the substring - it can't hold as much as is trying to be put in ? is there another method very similar that would function in this way without using a substring ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  public string formatText(string textData)
  { 
            textData = new Regex(@" {2,}").Replace(textData.Trim(), @" ");
            var left = Console.CursorLeft; var top = Console.CursorTop; var lines = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; textData.Length > 0; i++)
            {
                lines.Add(textData.Substring(0, Math.Min(Console.WindowWidth, textData.Length)));
                var length = lines[i].LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                if (length > 0) lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(length);
                textData = textData.Substring(Math.Min(lines[i].Length + 1, textData.Length));
                Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top + i); Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            }
  }
```

and if `columnLimit` is important then following may help you

```
public string formatText(string longSentenceParts,int columnLimit)
{
        string[] words = longSentence.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        IList<string> longSentenceParts = new List<string>();
        longSentenceParts.Add(string.Empty);

        int partCounter = 0;

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if ((longSentenceParts[partCounter] + word).Length > columnLimit)
            {
                partCounter++;
                longSentenceParts.Add(string.Empty);
            }

            longSentenceParts[partCounter] += word + " ";
        }

        foreach (string x in longSentenceParts)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```